# button not working for hmtl2canvas asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, button

I am trying to use html2canvas to capture a div in my html and save it to a pdf file in asp.net.  I was recommended to use the below javascript code to make this happen, but the code is not executed on the click event?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
            document.getElementById("Print_Button").addEventListener("OnItemCommand", (function () {
                html2canvas(document.getElementById("form1"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        cvs = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                        cvs.save("mcn.pdf")
                    }
                });
            }));


    });
```

The attributes for the button are:

ID="Print_Button"  runat="server"  Text="Print MCN" type ="input"

Comment: Remove the attribute `runat="server"` from the button as that causes postback, making the page reload.

Comment: Hi @Archer, I have stopped the button posting back to the server, but now it does nothing at all?  I'm not sure where it is all going wrong?  Would appreciate any help at all, been trying to get this to work for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour in ASP.NET Web Forms is that any id of a control with runat="server" gets transformed to ensure that there's not an ID conflict. So your button and your form will likely not have the id:s you used in your code (unless they have ClientIdMode set to static)

So start by setting ClientIdMode to static on both the form and the button if that's a problem.

This is the code I used when testing (using jQuery), and it works fine for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script>


    $(function() {
            $("#Print_Button").on("click", function () {
                html2canvas($("#form1"), {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                        var pdf = new jsPDF();

                        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
                        var download = document.getElementById('download');

                        pdf.save("download.pdf");
                    }
                });
            });


    });
</script>
```

I removed the cvs.save("...")-row, because the data you get is a string containig a base64-encoded image like "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo....==". So it doesn't have a save method.
But by using the jspdf-library, you can still save it as a PDF on the client side

Answer (score -1):

call **htmlcanvasdownload()** to have event listened

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    htmlcanvasdownload();
    function htmlcanvasdownload() {
        document.getElementById("Print_Button").addEventListener("OnItemCommand", (function () {
            html2canvas(document.getElementById("form1"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    cvs = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    cvs.save("mcn.pdf")
                }
            });
        }));

    }
});
```

Ok you edited your question, next listen for click,

```
document.getElementById("Print_Button").addEventListener("click", function(){
   //..process canvas
   return false;//stop event going to server
});
```

checking if html2canvas works:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("form1"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var cvs = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            //this emage need to be posted to server 
            //var file=new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
            // with ajax or with form post
            // as blob to a input type file or as imput type text where you send image/png as base64

            //this will open your image
            window.open(cvs);
        },
        width:320,
        height:220
    });
```

Comment: Hi @SilentTremor, thank you for your answer.  I have just tried that and still nothing happens, not even an error notification.  I wonder am I missing something that I am supposed to use in asp.net for html2canvas to work.  When I click the button now, it just refreshes the page.  There is C# in one of the tables cells on that page with a timestamp, and it just updates everytime I click the button, but nothing else?

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping some of the code in the function `htmlcanvasdownload()`?  I can't see how that makes any difference at all.

Comment: He/She edited the question, was without htmlcanvasdownload() call

Comment: Hi @Archer, sorry that was an error when I originally posted.

Comment: I'm still having no luck...I added @SilentTremor adjustment above and still no change.  It's as though html2canvas does not want to work, even though I have added the reference files to my project as well.

Comment: Add an alert before html2canvas call to check if click event is corect registered